# Orchard module not appearing in list of modules

Tags: model-view-controller, module, orchardcms, codeplex

Downloaded the source code for an Orchard module from Codeplex and added using VS2012 to my copy of the Orchard source. When I run the source the new module is not available to enable.

Comment: Have you built it? What module is it?

Answer (score 0):

It probably doesn't build. Check your logs, and if you still can't see what's wrong, attach a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Hazza and Bertrand - Fixed it by unzipping into the modules folder then added the existing project from the modules folder rather than from my download folder.